# find -exec with parameters in groovy

Tags: unix, groovy, sh

I have a pipeline in Jenkins that calls a groovy script which does some important stuff and after its finished doing that stuff it runs a shell command which is supposed to run another shell script.

```
script {
        sh "git config --global user.name 'Jenkins'; 
        git config --global user.email 'someone@email.com';
        echo ${params.SELECTED_TEMPLATES} > selected_templates.cfg; 
        find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace -name 'execute-test.sh' -type f 
        -exec chmod 755 {} ';' 
        -exec ${SF_USERNAME} ${SF_PASSWORD} {} ';'"
        }
```

Log:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Ideally, it should pass the variables to the 'execute-test.sh' and run it... I don't know how to make it understand that the variables are variables that I want to pass. Hope you can help me out, thank you!

Comment: What do `SF_USERNAME` and `SF_PASSWORD` contain? What do you expect that `-exec` to do?

Comment: SF_USERNAME and SF_PASSWORD are credentials that the groovy file retrieves from Jenkins, I want -exec to run the 'execute-test.sh' and pass the two variables/parameters to it

Comment: `-exec ${SF_USERNAME}` will attempt to use `${SF_USERNAME}` as the name of a command; surely that's not what you intend?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I do not intend. What I really want, as described in my comment above, is to run the shell script and pass these variables to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your comments correctly, you are looking for

```
-exec {} ${SF_USERNAME} ${SF_PASSWORD} ';'
```

which will execute the found file with the two variables as parameters.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions, thanks for that! I get this error however: `+ find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace -name execute-test.sh -type f -execdir chmod 755 {} ; -execdir {} ****

find: missing argument to '-execdir'`

Comment: Your example didn't have `-execdir`, why did you switch to that and take out the useful arguments to it?

Comment: I just found out about execdir and thought it would make sense to use that. I didn't take out the arguments, the **** is SF_USERNAME which is a credential and therefore Jenkins is censoring it

Comment: You seem to be lacking the training semicolon though.

Comment: With `-execdir` you probably want `-execdir ./{} arguments ';'` with a relative path `./` as well.

Comment: I tested it with Jenkins and its not working, if I test only this command though through the terminal it technically works - at least it does not throw errors at me. I think that the groovy script might have problems interpreting it correctly (SF_USERNAME is like john.doe@company.environment.com) maybe the @ or dots cause issues, could explain why only the first parameter is shown - what do you think about that?

Comment: I know squat about Groovy and very little about Jenkins, so, sorry, no idea.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help, I think I am closer to the solution now than before.